# Is Expression Trees a core language feature of C#?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Are Expression Trees a core language feature or a feature of the BCL object/library? Is it something that you can't build without the core language features of C#?

Comment: To the extent that there is an implicit cast from  a lambda of the form `Func<T1, T2>` to `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` that the compiler must be doing at compile time, I think so.

Comment: You can use the builder methods instead of translating a lambda expression to an expression tree. But it's *a lot* more verbose.

Comment: Which part of the feature are you asking about?

Comment: @TimothyShields That's backwards. The conversion is from `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` to `Func<T1, T2>`.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris It's neither. An expression lambda can be used as both `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` and `Func<T1, T2>`.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris You can convert an `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` to a `Func<T1, T2>` of course.  What I was referring to was the compiler's ability to turn `(int x) => 3 * x + 2` into an expression tree.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris: No such _implicit_ conversion exists.  (other than the `Compile()` method, which is not magic)

Comment: @Slaks Interesting. So the compiler optimizes the lambda directly into a function/delegate it compile time? Where do I learn more of this?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris: Which `this` are you referring to?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris: Both of the following lines are valid code: Expression<Func<int, int>> squaredEx = (x) => x * x; Func<int, int> squaredFunc = (x) => x * x;

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to turn the lambda in the first into an expression, and the lambda in the second into a func, even though those are fairly different things.

Comment: @Shlomo sure, but what I'm getting at is that the compiler can convert `lambda -> expression` and `expression -> function`, so why should there be extra code for `lambda -> function` if we could just do `lambda -> expression -> function` at compile time. I'm sure that either way, the compiler converts the lambda first to an expression, even if that expression is not a .NET expression, but rather the internal representation of an expression in the compiler.

Comment: @Slaks, I'm wondering where I can find out more information about how the compiler compiles C# lambdas into expressions or functions/delegates.

Comment: Also, why did everyone jump to "Oh he doesn't know lamdas can be compiled into expressions and functions..."

Comment: @ChristopherHarris I don't think anybody was trying to jump on you. :)

Answer (score 3):

No, expression trees are not a language feature. They are usable from any .NET language so they cannot be C# specific. They are ordinary CLR types defined in a built-in assembly.

The construction through lambda expressions (and LINQ) is C# specific. But you can always construct an equivalent `Expression` manually. The C# compiler itself does nothing more than to emit calls to the well-known `Expression` static construction methods. You can inspect what the compiler emits by decompiling the binary with Reflector configured to an old .NET version.

Whether expression trees use .NET Framework internal APIs is an unrelated question, but I cannot think of any reason why they would need to.

Comment: "No, they are not a language feature. They are usable from any .NET language so they cannot be C# specific." - This isn't right. They *are* a language feature of C# ... and F# ... and Visual Basic ... ---- Each needs to know the language syntax and such to actually create an expression tree from the text in your source file.

Comment: @Timothy: No, you are referring to _lambda expressions_. _Those_ are language features. The `Expression` classes themselves are just regular .NET classes. Anything that can use .NET classes can use the `Expression` classes.

Comment: @JeffMercado Oh...right. I was thinking the original question was about the lambda-expression-to-`Expression` feature, not the `Expression` classes themselves. Yes, those are not language features. :)

Comment: Expression Trees can be constructed from lambdas in VB as well, just with different syntax

Comment: The fact that Expression classes are a part of .NET framework alone doesnt put it outside the scope of language. As @TimothyShields mentions in comments section, there exist an implicit conversion from lambda expressions to Expression types, which is not something you can do with your custom classes. I would not say its a core language feature, but its intrinsically tied to compiler. So goes with foreach on `GetEnumerator`, collection initializer sugar for `Add` methods of `IEnumerable`s, `using` clause for `IDisposable`s, `Exception`s can be thrown, `Attribute` class etc.

Comment: @nawfal what you're saying has been discussed in the comments above: expression trees do not require the existence of C#. Therefore they are not a C# feature. I can write my own expression trees that are every bit as functional as the built-in ones. Automatic generation of expression trees is the C# feature. That's different.

Comment: @usr I think we both are meaning the same, may be with different words which is confusing. I was wrong to say intrinsically tied. Could you write a `Expression<TDelegate>` class that is implicitly compatible with a lambda expression? May be apart from that class, everything is outside the scope of language.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the `Expression` class definition, it is defined in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace. This, Expression is not a C# language feature - it is a class that is consumable by all languages that target the CLR.

Here, for example, is an article on MSDN titled "[Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)" illustrating how to create and consume Expression trees using C# and VB.NET.